# Javascript Functions (Multiple)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have 1 function inside of each of my 4 radio buttons with onclick attributes I've set inside my input tags.

My goal is to change the values of 2 variables depending on which radio button you click.

However, once the value of the variables change an extra function would be called outside/seperately showing me the new value of the 2 variables.

The problem is I can only keep my variable inside of the 4 functions and can't use them outside of them for the new function I'm using. What should I do? Could I have a basic example?

I'm kind of new here, not sure how to post code so I made a hastebin:
https://hasteb.in/hefehoqi.xml

Comment: Can you please post the code you've currently got

Comment: _**I can only keep my variable inside of the 4 functions**_ what do you mean by this? Just define it outside of your functions and make it become global. Then use it anywhere.

Comment: You've functions inside radio buttons? Do you mean you've inline event handlers? Please show the code you have..

Comment: I've added a hastebin.. I tried adding the code on here but it said something about it not being properly indented..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the variables you wanna use are `module` and `tmodule`.
So like I said in the comment sections. Just define them outside of the functions.

```
let module = '';
let tmodule = 1;

function radio1(){
    let radio1 = true;
    module = 'module1';
    tmodule = 1;
    alert('radio1 function');
}

function radio2(){
    let radio1 = true;
    module = 'module2';
    tmodule = 2;
    alert('radio2 function');
}
function radio3(){
    let radio1 = true;
    module = 'module3';
    tmodule = 'tmodule3';
    alert('radio3 function');
}
function radio4(){
    let radio1 = true;
    module = 'module4';
    tmodule = 'tmodule4';
    alert('radio4 function');
}

function commencer(){   
    console.log(module);
    console.log(tmodule);
    document.getElementById("module1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("module2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("module3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("module4").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("module1").innerHTML = "";
}
```